# Modificar atributo tag html después de insertarlo con jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome

Creé una variable `a` y le asigné el tag `<a>` y 3 atributos, href, target, y html(es el texto que muestra el `a`), luego lo inserté dentro de un section con id #app-body mediante jQuery, de esta forma `$('#app-body').append(a)` luego de esto quiero cambiarle los atributos, y me deja cambiar todo excepto el atributo html(es el texto que muestra el `a`).

Aquí les dejo el código

```
var a = $('<a>', {
    href: 'https://www.google.co.ve',
    target: '_blank',
    html: 'Ir a Google'
})

$('#app-body').append(a)

a.attr({
    href: 'https://www.twitter.com',
    target: '_blank',
    html: 'Ir a Twitter'
})
```

**el tag a en el html me sigue diciendo ir a google**

Comment: puedes intentar primero borrar el contenido `a.attr('html', ' ')` y después ya le asignas el nuevo valor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cambiar el html con jQuery necesitas usar `.html()` asi:

```js
var a = $('<a>', {
    href: 'https://www.google.co.ve',
    target: '_blank',
    html: 'Ir a Google'
});

$('#app-body').append(a);

a.attr({
    href: 'https://www.twitter.com',
    target: '_blank'    
});
a.html('Ir a Twitter');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app-body"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que está sucediendo es que primero declaras la variable `a` que contiene el elemento que quieres insertar, después añades ese elemento al DOM. El elemento que está en el DOM y la variable ahora son dos cosas distintas, si tú modificas la variable no verás ningún cambio reflejado. Lo que puedes hacer es agregar un id al elemento `a`(no la variable, al elemento del DOM) y cambiarlo.

```js
var a = $('<a>', {
    href: 'https://www.google.co.ve',
    target: '_blank',
    html: 'Ir a Google'
}).attr('id','anchor');

$('#app-body').append(a);
$('#anchor').attr('href','https://www.twitter.com');
$('#anchor').text('Ir a Twitter');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='app-body'></div>
```